# How to discover why canvas.requestFullscreen() failed?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, dart, webgl, fullscreen

Task at hand is to add support for fullscreen mode to an WebGL application written in Dart.

canvas.requestFullscreen() works for simple test cases, but fails on the full app.

Please point out the way to tell what is preventing the browser from switching to fullscreen.

The code is:

```dart
void trapFullscreenError() {
  document.onFullscreenError.listen((e) {
    log("fullscreenerror: $e");
  });
}

void toggleFullscreen(CanvasElement c) {
  log(
      "fullscreenSupport=${document.fullscreenEnabled} fullscreenElement=${document.fullscreenElement}"
      );

  if (document.fullscreenElement != null) {
    log("exiting fullscreen");
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else {
    log("requesting fullscreen");
    c.requestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

In Chrome that code results in:

```
fullscreenSupport=true fullscreenElement=null
requesting fullscreen
fullscreenerror: Instance of 'Event'
```

Dartium debugger shows these fields:

```
Event [id=4]
_selector null
bubbles true
cancelable false
clipboardData null
currentTarget #document [id=5]
defaultPrevented false
eventPhase 3
hashCode 234642739
path NodeList[6] [id=6]
target canvas#main_canvas [id=7]
timeStamp 1398779450832
type "webkitfullscreenerror"
```

Comment: What is the output of `log("fullscreenerror: ${e.detail}");`?

Comment: It throws an exception: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
J.get$detail$x
trapFullscreenError_closure.call$1 fullscreen.dart:9
invokeClosure_closure0.call$0 js_helper.dart:1842
_IsolateContext.eval$1 isolate_helper.dart:392
_callInIsolate isolate_helper.dart:30
invokeClosure js_helper.dart:1842
(anonymous function)

Comment: Is this only in JavaScript or also in Dart. What browsers did you try?

Comment: Dartium throws this: Class 'Event' has no instance getter 'detail'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'detail'
Receiver: Instance of 'Event'
Arguments: []

Comment: The javascript result is from Chrome. Dart requestFullscreen compiled to JS does not work on other browsers. There are bugs for this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4136
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10246
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11506

Comment: Can you try to set a breakpoint in the event handler and check the type of the argument `e`? I wrongly assumed an Event type instead of an Error type. Can you investigate if the argument `e` has some fields that contain additional information.

Comment: I have added to the question the fields of e according Dartium debugger.

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125 (can only be called from a mouse or keyboard event)

Comment: Yeah, that solved it. I had to modify how events are handled. If you post it as answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For security reasons `requestFullscreen` can only be called in an event handler of a keyboard or click event.

see also [Javascript request fullscreen is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still on this. But I've managed to make it work by identifying the domElement in the renderer, inside an event

```
renderer.domElement.requestFullscreen()
```