# Javascript fullscreen api and window height

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I am trying to get $(window).height() after fullscreen api fires up. All other supported browser works just fine but Chrome getting window height wrong (sometimes). Its like it missing the fact that the window size has changed. My code is below:

```
function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

.

```
launchFullscreen(element);
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Could the `launchFullscreen` function be running asynchronously, and so the height is being calculated before fullscreen is enabled?

Comment: I know you're right. But webkitRequestFullscreen don't have callback function. So how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was missing here. fullscreen api has a change event.

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    //do something
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
    //do something
}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    //do something
}, false);

document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
   //do something
}, false);
```

Comment: may be interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable

Comment: it does not help me in chrome , it produces wrong height even in onchange listeners

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //do something
    }, 50);
}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //do something
    }, 50);
}, false);
```