# Inject javascript into YouTube to make video fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm writing a Chrome extension to alter the functionality of YouTube. I have code injected onto the page, and I'm trying to trigger fullscreen of the video in certain circumstances.

I've done everything I can think of, but to no avail.

Double-clicking the video:

```
$('video').click();
setTimeout(function() {
  $('video').click();
}, 40);
```

But this way doesn't work. I'm not sure why, but I think Youtube expects a 'real' click or something?

Simulating the 'f' keypress:

```
var event = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
event.initUIEvent("keypress", true, true, window, 1);
event.keyCode = 70;
```

And dozens of variations of the above, none seem to work. Think it might be a Webkit thing.

Linking to a video in the format: `https://www.youtube.com/v/<vid-id>`. But this won't suit my purposes because I need to be able to call it again after page load.

Anyone any ideas on how to make Youtube full screen after page load via Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube probably is using the requestFullScreen Javascript API to take the video player to fullscreen.

Per specifications of requestFullScreen API, it must be **triggered by direct user interaction.**

This means you will not be able to force the player to full screen unless you have a button that a user clicks or something of that nature.

Related SO Question:

[Javascript request fullscreen is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable)

Comment: Yeah, you may have a point. It works in the console, but not in code. What a troll.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var vid = $("video");
if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
  vid.requestFullscreen();
} else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
   vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a double click, just use dblclick() javascript function.

Also, instead of doing a dblclick on video, you could try doing a click on the fullscreen button of youtube video.