# Vue-fullscreen error with user-generated event

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I am using the vue-fullscreen plugin to trigger a fullscreen of an element in my code. I am calling the function using @click, yet despite that I am getting the following error:

Firefox:

> Request for fullscreen was denied because Element.requestFullscreen()
>   was not called from inside a short running user-generated event
>   handler.

Chrome:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.

As per threads like the following, [Javascript request fullscreen is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable#9747340), I have have found the following warnings:

- Make sure it is generated directly by a user click.

I think I am.

- Make sure there is not more than a 1 second delay between the user generated action and the function.

I find no delay, especially given the function is incredibly short and direct.

- If you are using iframes, make sure you allow fullscreen parameters, including in any parent iframes.

I am not using an iframes.

Here is a snippet of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tool_circle_button" @click="toggleFullscreen"></div>
<fullscreen :fullscreen.sync="fullscreen">
   Content
</fullscreen>
```

Javascript:

```
toggleFullscreen () {
  console.log(this.fullscreen)
  this.fullscreen = !this.fullscreen
},
```

Do these errors suggest that the @click command is not being recognized as a user-generated click? If not, what else could be causing this? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: In case it matters, I should clarify the function is inside my methods.