# Make Unite Gallery full screen on document ready

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

So I am making a website for a restaurant, where the a la carte menu will load in a unite gallery on a separate web page. I would like for display purposes if the gallery would load in full screen mode. 
However I can't get it to load in full screen

http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=documentation#using_the_api

following the documentation
I have tried

```
var api;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            api = $("#gallery").unitegallery();
            $("#gallery").enterFullscreen();

          // I have tried this as well with no success api.enterFullscreen(); 
            });
```

Comment: so what is the exact issue you are facing here?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I am unable to get the gallery to load in full screen. I have also edited the question to clarify this

Comment: have you included the plugin js properly and there are no console error on browser? can you recreate it on jsfiddle or code snippet or provide the link of your website?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I am getting a warning 'Request for fullscreen was denied because Element.requestFullscreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable/9747340 is relevant

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks, it seems full screen has to be called through a user event for security reasons. I'm going to try and use an iframe as a work around