# Cannot toggle fullscreen in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a react page in an iframe with a button that can enter fullscreen mode. I've tested this manually with firefox and chrome which both work. However, clicking with testcafe does not go to fullscreen mode and fails the test.

I'm assuming the iframe isn't the issue because it works manually but wanted to mention it just in case.

This is some of the app:

```
fs.fullScreen = function () {
    const el = (fsEl && fsEl.current) || document.documentElement

    if (el.requestFullscreen) return el.requestFullscreen()
    if (el.mozRequestFullScreen) return el.mozRequestFullScreen()
    if (el.webkitRequestFullscreen) return el.webkitRequestFullscreen()
    if (el.msRequestFullscreen) return el.msRequestFullscreen()
  }

<button onClick={fs.fullScreen}>Fullscreen</button>
```

This is the test that fails:

```
beforeEach((t) => t.switchToIframe(storybook.iframe))
afterEach((t) => t.switchToMainWindow())

test('The Fullscreen button enters fullscreen mode', async (t) => {
  const { description, fullscreenButton } = storybook.hooks.fullscreen
  await t
    .expect(description.textContent)
    .contains('Browser not in fullscreen mode')
    .click(fullscreenButton)
    .expect(description.textContent)
    .contains('Browser in fullscreen mode')
})
```

In Firefox I've seen the console error: `Request for fullscreen was denied because Element.requestFullscreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.`

In Chrome, I've seen the console error: `Uncaught TypeError: fullscreen error`.

The firefox error is fairly clear but I don't know how to work around it with testcafe. There is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable) by editing the firefox profile before running the test but that won't work for chrome or other browsers. Is the chrome issue likely to be for the same reason?

This seems like it would be a common issue that automation frameworks have solved, so I might be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue in the simple example:
Test page:

```
<button id="btn">click me</button>

<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('btn');

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        button.requestFullscreen();
    });
</script>
```

Test code

```
test(`test`, async t => {
    await t.click('#btn');
});
```

I'm not sure whether this functionality will be supported or not, since we need to research it in detail.

As a workaround, you can mock the requestFullscreen method on the target element. It will suppress the error, but won't bring your page to the fullscreen layout. Check the following code as a reference:

```
const mockFullcreen = ClientFunction(element => element.requestFullscreen = () => {});

await mockFullcreen(target);

await t.click(target);
```