# reveal.js : cannot request full screen on video element (Firefox, Chromium)

Tags: javascript, firefox, reveal.js

While I can run the [plain Mozilla example](https://fullscreen-requestfullscreen-demo.glitch.me/) for putting a HTML5 `video` element into fullscreen based on key press, reveal.js must be doing something different or asynchronous regarding keypresses. When I try to do this using `Reveal.configure({ keyboard: { 116: putVideoInFullScreen }})`, Firefox (78) just complains:

> Request for fullscreen was denied because Element.requestFullscreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

Similarly, in Chromium:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Frankly, I don't understand why pressing a key is not a user gesture. I looked into the reveal.js source code, and it all seems to go straight through a registered keypress event handler.

A work-around using directly registered handler, like `document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress, false)` does not work either, because reveal.js "blocks" the events that were registered before, so even if I have `Reveal.configure({ keyboard: { 116: null }})`, the event handler doesn't receive the F5 press. Catch-22.

Can I force FF to allow me to put fullscreen in any case? How can I make this work?

---

Note that my FF screen *is already* in full-screen. What I want to do is toggle full screen for a `video` element, like

```js
var sl = Reveal.getCurrentSlide();
var e = sl.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
  if (e.paused) {
    e.play();
    e.requestFullscreen(); // !!!
} else {
  e.pause();
  document.exitFullscreen();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A work-around for Firefox is to disable the check, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable): In `about:config` set `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only` to `false`.