# Unity trying to make downloaded webGL game go fullscreen automatically

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have a Unity webGL game I downloaded from the web. I don't know what version of unity it was made in.

It starts playing in a small canvas with other stuff on the page like Unity logo, there is a button on the page that makes it fullscreen. I would like it to be fullscreen as soon as you load the page..

I tried adding this line to the script in index.html, to click the fullscreen button..

```
fullscreenButton.click();
```

But I get a load of errors..

[image]

here is the full index.html with the javascript in it. You can see the line I added near the bottom. I just tried clicking the button after unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1) is assigned to its onclick event (or whatever it is (I dunno anything about web).
I also tried just calling unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1) but I get the same error.
So how can I make it go fullscreen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | QTE</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-warning"> </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">QTE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var warningBanner = document.querySelector("#unity-warning");
     

      // Shows a temporary message banner/ribbon for a few seconds, or
      // a permanent error message on top of the canvas if type=='error'.
      // If type=='warning', a yellow highlight color is used.
      // Modify or remove this function to customize the visually presented
      // way that non-critical warnings and error messages are presented to the
      // user.
      function unityShowBanner(msg, type) {
        function updateBannerVisibility() {
          warningBanner.style.display = warningBanner.children.length ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = msg;
        warningBanner.appendChild(div);
        if (type == 'error') div.style = 'background: red; padding: 10px;';
        else {
          if (type == 'warning') div.style = 'background: yellow; padding: 10px;';
          setTimeout(function() {
            warningBanner.removeChild(div);
            updateBannerVisibility();
          }, 5000);
        }
        updateBannerVisibility();
      }

      var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/WebBuild.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/WebBuild.data",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/WebBuild.framework.js",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/WebBuild.wasm",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "Rat Bashers",
        productName: "QTE",
        productVersion: "0.1",
        showBanner: unityShowBanner,
      };

      // By default Unity keeps WebGL canvas render target size matched with
      // the DOM size of the canvas element (scaled by window.devicePixelRatio)
      // Set this to false if you want to decouple this synchronization from
      // happening inside the engine, and you would instead like to size up
      // the canvas DOM size and WebGL render target sizes yourself.
      // config.matchWebGLToCanvasSize = false;

      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // Mobile device style: fill the whole browser client area with the game canvas:

        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.name = 'viewport';
        meta.content = 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=yes';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        container.className = "unity-mobile";

        // To lower canvas resolution on mobile devices to gain some
        // performance, uncomment the following line:
        // config.devicePixelRatio = 1;

        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

        unityShowBanner('WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.');
      } else {
        // Desktop style: Render the game canvas in a window that can be maximized to fullscreen:

        canvas.style.width = "1280px";
        canvas.style.height = "720px";
      }

      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";
              
          unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
          fullscreenButton.click();  
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };      
      document.body.appendChild(script); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons requestFullscreen can only be called in an event handler of a keyboard or click event.

More details: [Javascript request fullscreen is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable/9747340#9747340)